# How can i set content type multipart form data in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

I have a problem with axios, i cant set content type to multipart/form-data. here's my code

````
  function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    const isLogin = authService.isLogin();
    if (isLogin) {
      const _auth = JSON.parse(isLogin);

      // const _superadmin = `cHJhdG9tby5hLm51Z3JvaG9AZ21haWwuY29tOmJlMTNlOTE1Yjg4MzEyMmVlMGRhNzZlNzBiYWU3ZjU1OTJmMGZlZGNiZTYzNWEyZmMyMDg0MWZhOGI3ZGQ0ZWQ=`;
      config.headers["Authorization"] = authService.isLogin()
        ? "Bearer " + _auth._token
        : "";

      config.headers["Accept"] = "application/json, text/plain, */*";
      config.headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data";
    }
    return config;
  }, ```

does anyone can help me to add content-type in my header request?
````

Answer (score 0):

Axios does not automatically set the multipart form boundary in Node, as a result, you must use getHeaders()

like :

```
const res = await axios.post('https://www.example.com/post', formData, {
  headers: formData.getHeaders()
});
```

in your case config.getHeaders() while you are sending the request